# Is there any limitation using aggregate function?

Tags: sql, ms-access

As long as I create a queries with the Ms Access SQL, with the code below

```
Select Pilots.PilotNum, Iif(Pilots.[PilotNum]=Bookings.[Captain], Sum(AIrplanes.[RentalRate])*0.25, Sum(AIrplanes.[RentalRate])*0.15)
FROM (Bookings INNER JOIN Airplanes ON Bookings.[AirplaneNum] = Airplanes.[AirplaneNum]) INNER JOIN Pilots ON Bookings.[CoCaptain]=Pilots.PilotNum Or Bookings.[Captain]=Pilots.[PilotNum]
GROUP BY Pilots.[PilotNum]
# ;
```

I will always get this error window.

[image]

I tried to google to find the answer but I can't solve it.

The link below is to my microsoft access file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B94jaWN21JifNI3mRP3mUJt_7z8rMVfU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Put the Iif logic inside the SUM() intstead.

Comment: TQ!!, I had solved my problem.

Comment: How was the problem solved, do share so others can learn.

Answer (score 0):

`Select Pilots.PilotNum, SUM(Iif(Pilots.[PilotNum]=Bookings.[Captain], (AIrplanes.[RentalRate]*0.25), (Sum(AIrplanes.[RentalRate])*0.15)) FROM (Bookings INNER JOIN Airplanes ON Bookings.[AirplaneNum] = Airplanes.[AirplaneNum]) INNER JOIN Pilots ON Bookings.[CoCaptain]=Pilots.PilotNum Or Bookings.[Captain]=Pilots.[PilotNum] GROUP BY Pilots.[PilotNum] ;`

The solution is here, Thanks for @jarlh!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).